# Tomboy notes not opening - addins not loaded

Tags: 11.10, tomboy

My tomboy notes is not opening.
I tried

```
sudo apt-get remove tomboy

sudo apt-get install tomboy
```

still not working

when i type tomboy in terminal i get.

> soma@ubuntu:~$ tomboy
>
> (Tomboy:6628): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
>
> (Tomboy:6628): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
>
> (Tomboy:6628): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
>
> (Tomboy:6628): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
>    [INFO 02:13:28.606] Initializing Mono.Addins
>   Add-in could not be loaded: Document element did not appear. file:///home/soma/.config/tomboy/addin-db-001/config.xml Line 1, position 1.
>   System.Xml.XmlException: Document element did not appear. file:///home/soma/.config/tomboy/addin-db-001/config.xml Line 1, position 1.
>     at Mono.Xml2.XmlTextReader.Read () [0x00000] in :0 
>     at System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Read () [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Mono.Xml.EntityResolvingXmlReader.Read () [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Mono.Xml.DTDValidatingReader.ReadContent () [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Mono.Xml.DTDValidatingReader.Read () [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Mono.Xml.Schema.XsdValidatingReader.Read () [0x00000] in :0 
>     at System.Xml.XmlValidatingReader.Read () [0x00000] in :0 
>     at System.Xml.XmlDocument.ReadNodeCore (System.Xml.XmlReader reader) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at System.Xml.XmlDocument.ReadNode (System.Xml.XmlReader reader) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load (System.Xml.XmlReader xmlReader) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load (System.String filename) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Mono.Addins.Database.DatabaseConfiguration.Read (System.String file) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Mono.Addins.Database.AddinDatabase.get_Configuration () [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Mono.Addins.Database.AddinDatabase.IsRegisteredForUninstall (System.String domain, System.String addinId) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Mono.Addins.AddinRegistry.IsRegisteredForUninstall (System.String addinId) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Mono.Addins.AddinRegistry.GetAddin (System.String id) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Mono.Addins.AddinEngine.ResolveLoadDependencies (System.Collections.ArrayList addins, System.Collections.Stack depCheck, System.String id, Boolean optional) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Mono.Addins.AddinEngine.LoadAddin (IProgressStatus statusMonitor, System.String id, Boolean throwExceptions) [0x00000] in :0 
>   Exception in Gtk# callback delegate
>     Note: Applications can use GLib.ExceptionManager.UnhandledException to handle the exception.
>   System.Xml.XmlException: Document element did not appear. file:///home/soma/.config/tomboy/addin-db-001/config.xml Line 1, position 1.
>     at Mono.Xml2.XmlTextReader.Read () [0x00000] in :0 
>     at System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Read () [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Mono.Xml.EntityResolvingXmlReader.Read () [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Mono.Xml.DTDValidatingReader.ReadContent () [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Mono.Xml.DTDValidatingReader.Read () [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Mono.Xml.Schema.XsdValidatingReader.Read () [0x00000] in :0 
>     at System.Xml.XmlValidatingReader.Read () [0x00000] in :0 
>     at System.Xml.XmlDocument.ReadNodeCore (System.Xml.XmlReader reader) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at System.Xml.XmlDocument.ReadNode (System.Xml.XmlReader reader) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load (System.Xml.XmlReader xmlReader) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load (System.String filename) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Mono.Addins.Database.DatabaseConfiguration.Read (System.String file) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Mono.Addins.Database.AddinDatabase.get_Configuration () [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Mono.Addins.Database.AddinDatabase.RunPendingUninstalls (IProgressStatus monitor) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Mono.Addins.Database.AddinDatabase.Update (IProgressStatus monitor, System.String domain) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Mono.Addins.AddinRegistry.Update (IProgressStatus monitor) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Tomboy.AddinManager.InitializeMonoAddins (System.String old_conf_dir) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Tomboy.AddinManager..ctor (System.String tomboy_conf_dir, System.String old_tomboy_conf_dir) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Tomboy.NoteManager.Initialize () [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Tomboy.Tomboy+c_*AnonStorey2.<>m*_0 () [0x00000] in :0 
>     at GLib.Timeout+TimeoutProxy.Handler () [0x00000] in :0 
>      at GLib.ExceptionManager.RaiseUnhandledException(System.Exception e, Boolean is_terminal)
>      at GLib.Timeout+TimeoutProxy.Handler()
>      at Gtk.Application.gtk_main()
>      at Gtk.Application.Run()
>      at Tomboy.GnomeApplication.StartMainLoop()
>      at Tomboy.Application.StartMainLoop()
>      at Tomboy.Tomboy.StartTrayIcon()
>      at Tomboy.Tomboy.Main(System.String[] args)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your config file is corrupted. It is an XML file which has been mangled

The solution is to simply remove the directory containing this config file.
The line which makes it clear it

*file:///home/soma/.config/tomboy/addin-db-001/config.xml Line 1, position 1*

Make sure that tomboy is not running, then run this command

```
rm -rf ~/.config/tomboy/addin-db-001
```

Then start Tomboy, it will create the necessary config file as required

---

Deleting is not changing anything since the problem was with the config file and not with the actual tomboy installation

Next time you post a question you might want to make sure that when posting the stacktrace you do not put your information like username. You might not mind, I am just informing. Some people consider it personal/private

Comment: IT WORKED!!!!!! :)

Comment: @Newbi If it works, it would be good to mark this as answered.